# Firebase - Strange behavior on App Engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Currently using Firebase 3.0.2 on Java App Engine.  I'm deploying to a basic scaling module.  My goal is to export some data from the datastore to firebase.  I'm using a taskqueue to process one entity from the datastore at a time.   I am attempting to add Car objects from the datastore into Firebase.  After completion of the transaction (I want to keep the same Ids and be able to update this data, thus the transaction) I want to add data to the autosuggest/cars/  path and update a counter (also using a transaction).

So the structure I am building is this:

```
{
 "autosuggest": { 
    "cars" {
        "bu": {
             "123": {
                  "name": "buick"
              }
       }
},
"cars": {
    "123": {
         "name" : "buick",
         "desc": "Big car"
      }
},
"stats": {
     "carCt": 1
   }
}
```

However, I am getting strange results, such as transactions not completing.  I am also getting data in /autosuggest/cars/, with carIds as the key.  CarIds are used for keys in /cars only in the code.
      FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("cars").child(String.valueOf(cars.getId())).runTransaction(new Handler() {
            @Override
            public Result doTransaction(MutableData mutableData) {
                mutableData.setValue(department);
                return Transaction.success(mutableData);
            }

```
        @Override
        public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, boolean b, DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if (databaseError != null) {

            } else {
                addToAutoSuggestForString(car, String.valueOf(car.getId()));
                incrementCarCounter();
            }
        }
    });

 private void incrementCarCounter() {
     FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("stats").child("carCt").runTransaction(new Handler() {
        @Override
        public Result doTransaction(MutableData mutableData) {
            Integer currentData = mutableData.getValue(Integer.class);
            if (currentData == null) {
                mutableData.setValue(1);
            } else {
                mutableData.setValue(currentData + 1);
            }
            return com.google.firebase.database.Transaction.success(mutableData);
        }

        @Override
        public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, boolean b, DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if (databaseError != null) {
                log.info("error");
            } else {
                log.info("Firebase counter increment succeeded.");
            }
        }
    });
}
 private void addAutoSuggestForString(final AutoCompleteResult result, String name) {
  FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("autosuggest/cars").child(searchStr + "/" + result.getKey()).setValue(result);
    }
}
```

Is there anything in the code above that would cause strange behavior and/or transactions to fail?  Is running this is a taskqueue of with max rate 10/s an issue?  The internals of Firebase sdk are a bit of a mystery.  Is calling Firebase.getInstance().getReference() over and over OK, or is this opening a seperate websocket each time?

Comment: Calling `getReference()` repeatedly is just fine. I don't see anything wrong with your code, though it'd be helpful if the first code snippet was complete (what leads up to the onComplete handler at the beginning?). If "searchStr" is from the user, you may need to sanitize it to make sure it doesn't include / or any disallowed characters (., $, #, [, ], /)

There may be an issue with the SDK where it loses its connection to Firebase after 60 minutes (I'm trying to confirm). Would that match up with your symptoms by chance? Else, please provide a MCVE (https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: SearchStr is being sanitized. I have seen the issue where the SDK loses connection after an hour, appears to be auth token expiring.  Only notice that when I hang onto DatabaseRef instead of getting a new instance every time.  For the time being I'm using the REST API from app engine, however I lose ability to use transactions, which I will need eventually.  Wondering what implementation details are of SDK?  Are jobs passed to queue for threads?  How many open connections are being used?  I have ran into App Engine socket quota limits before and it is difficult to know how they are being used.

Comment: I don't see any mention of manual scaling here, which [is required to use Firebase with GAE](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/mobile/firebase-app-engine-android-studio#configuring_the_app_engine_backend_to_use_manual_scaling), since ThreadManager is restricted with auto-scale in GAE.

Comment: I mentioned basic scaling, which supports the same threading capabilities as manual scaling.  Firebase SDK will simply fail if ran on an automatic scaling instance, and that is not what is happening here

Comment: We queue operations to run on a dedicated background thread that we maintain.  There's also a thread that manages our connection to the database backend. We keep a single persistent socket open for that, so I don't think socket quotas would be an issue.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I definitely was hitting a quota limit on sockets.  Guessing it was one of the burst limits on data transfer due to lot of tasks ran in one minute.  "Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy$OverQuotaException: The API call remote_socket.GetSocketOptions() required more quota than is available."